# Efficiently assign jobs to processes in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, data-analysis

I am trying to solve an interesting parallelization problem with python.

Let's say I have some data that needs to be processed and I have 2 processes running in parallel using multiprocessing.

I can split my data into 2 parts, giving one part to each process:

```py
data = [a, b, c, d, e]
data_process1 = [a, b, c]
data_process2 = [d, e]
```

As it turnes out, processing time for each data point varies, meaning a, b and c could take 1 minute each, but d and e take 10 minutes each. But how long a part of data takes to process can not be said before starting to process.

Doing it this way, I would achieve a total runtime of 20 minutes, as process 1 takes 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 minutes, but process 2 takes 10 + 10 = 20 minutes.

Now my idea is: Instead of splitting the data and assigning it all to processes, I could instead store the data parts in some sort of queue and make it more dynamic. Now, every time a process is free, it could retrieve the next item from the queue.

This way, process 1 is finished processing its items after 3 minutes, while process 2 is still working on d. Now, Process 1 can retrieve data e as the next data point to process. In total, we would achieve a runtime of 13 minutes (1+1+1+10 for process 1, 10 minutes for process 2).

Is there any way of assigning jobs dynamically is described?

Comment: Note, that 2 processes do not know which parts of data are more time consuming, so it could be that 2 processes pick `d` and `e` from the very start if arranging dynamic processing.

Comment: Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.

Comment: If you created a  multiprocessing pool with 2 processes with `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)` and then executed `results = pool.map(processing_function, [a, b, c, d, e])` where `processing_function` takes as an argument a single element from your list, you would achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to your question. This is an example of what I mean:

```py
import multiprocessing

def worker(value):
    import time
    import os

    # simulate doing some CPU-intensive work:
    time.sleep(.3)

    print('This process id =', os.getpid(), 'passed value =', value)
    return value ** 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]


    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    results = pool.map(worker, data)
    print(results)

    # clean up pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```None
This process id = 14808 passed value = 2
This process id = 17108 passed value = 1
This process id = 17108 passed value = 8
This process id = 14808 passed value = 4
This process id = 17108 passed value = 16
[1, 4, 16, 64, 256]
```

Comment: Note that `multiprocessing.Pool.map` will by default batch the iterable into chunks and submit each chunk as a single task. If a lot of expensive inputs end up in the same chunk, they will all be assigned to the same process, even if other processes finish working early. You can control this with the `chunksize` parameter, but smaller chunks add more communication overhead, so there's a tradeoff.

Comment: The default chunk sizing is undocumented, but currently, [the code tries to give each process about 4 chunks, if it can](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L481).

Comment: @user2357112 The code computes the *chunksize*  as `math.ceil(itreable_size / (4 * pool_size))`, which is more or less what you say (this turns out to be 1 for an iterable size of 5 and a pool size of 2). But the problem of specifying explicitly a *chunksize* of 1 is, as you said, can result in much slower processing for large iterables. Having some tasks taking much longer than others and ending up in the same chunk is probably not that frequent an occurrence in real life.

Comment: If what @user2357112 states is true, then this does not solve my issue, as I would like to minimize free processes while others are still working.

Comment: @DaVincr And do you think will do that? A chunksize of 1 will minimize the number of free processes (it may result, however, in an increased run time). You can explicitly specify *chunksize=1* on the call to `pool.map`. In the code I posted above a chunksize value of 1 will be computed given the number of tasks being submitted and the pool size.